# how to print the values of a file in the ie window in ajax call

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a php script that I call via ajax to echo out the values of a file. When I use IE, I get a pop up window to save the file, when I use chrome browser I get the values printed right on the browser (this is what I need). How could I modify the script or ajax call so that IE prints the values on the browser rather than giving me save option?

my get_data.php file is this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
$file = file_get_contents('C:/data.txt');
echo trim($file);
?>
```

my ajax call is this:

```
$.getJSON('get_data.php', function(data) {
```

when get_data.php called via the ajax, it displays the output of data.txt which is already a json format.

Comment: `$.getJSON('get_data.php', function(data) {` what does the function do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try changing the content type:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Wich is the correct mime type for json strings.
Or if you are just interested in displaying the file's contents:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```